# C - create a string "from" struct parameter

Tags: c, string, strcat

Have a

```
typedef struct person {
    char name[20]
    char surname[20]
} person_t;
```

I need to create a string like `XXXXXX:YYYYYY` with the function like
`char* personToString(person_t *p)`. I tried to make it:

```
char* personToString(person_t* p) {

  int n1,n2;
  n1=strlen(p->name);
  n2=strlen(p->surname);
  char *p = (char*) malloc((n1+n2+2)*sizeof(char));
  strcat(p,puser->name);
  strcat(p,":");
  strcat(p,puser->surname);

  return p;
}
```

This give me a reasonable output but I have some errors testing with valgrind! I also think that there is a way more classy to write the function!

Comment: Include the errors as they are pertinent to the question.

Comment: you can use `sprintf` instead of `strcat`, like `sprintf(p, "%s:%s", p->name, p->surname);`, plus u override `p`, u get it as parameter and then declare it as `char *` and you dont `free` your `char *`

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is not necessary since it's always `1`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `struct person *p` instead of `person_t`, since `person_t` is an object and not `typedef`?

Comment: i'm addinf also char ':' so i think i need +2!
I tried with +1 and give me errors

Comment: @RedX +2 is fine he is including ":" also in the final string

Comment: @SanyamGoel You are right. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 3):

When you malloc memory for `p` the memory will hold garbage values. Strcat will append a string after the null character, but in an uninitialized string will hold random values.

Replace the first strcat with strcpy.

Answer (score 3):

You need to

```
strcpy(p,puser->name);
```

not

```
strcat(p,puser->name);
```

`malloc` does not initialize the buffer to zero, so strcat is searching for a null byte in p first and probably not finding one, reading past the end of the buffer and thus crashing.

Instead of one strcpy plus two strcat you can also write one call to sprintf:

```
sprintf(p, "%s:%s", puser->name, puser->surname);
```

Comment: you're right :D thank you so much! (st**id error for me)
Even if it works well, do you think there's a way more classy to write the code?

Comment: Werner, You beaten us, your method is more appropriate to concatenate more then one strings. + to your answer. Nice

Comment: @user2590319 I'ld use sprintf. VoidPointer's implementation looks quite good to me.

Answer (score 2):

First you should call string copy, then strcat:

```
strcat(p,puser->name);
```

should be:

```
strcpy(p,puser->name);
```

because memory allocated with malloc function keeps values garbage,  by doing strcat for first you are concatenating after garbage -- it also brings Undefined behaviour in your code.

You can use [`void* calloc (size_t num, size_t size);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) instead of malloc(), calloc function initialized allocated memory with `0` (then strcat() no problem). 
Also dynamically allocated memory you should deallocate memory block using [`void free (void* ptr);)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/?kw=free) explicitly.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, Valgrind might be complaining about not `free`ing the memory

Answer (score 2):

This looks good to me,

```
char* personToString( struct person_t *p )
{
  int len = strlen(p->name) + strlen(p->surname) + 2; // holds ':' + NULL 
  char *str = malloc( len ); // Never cast malloc's return value in C

  // Check str for NULL
  if( str == NULL )
  {
      // we are out of memory
      // handle errors
      return NULL;
  }

  snprintf( str, len, "%s:%s", p->name, p->surname);

  return str;
}
```

**NOTE:**

1. Never cast `malloc`'s return value in C.
2. Use `snprintf` when multiple `strcat` is needed, its elegant.
3. `free` the return value `str` here in caller.

*Fixed `struct` and `char` variables*.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `struct person *p` instead of `person_t`, since `person_t` is an object and not `typedef`?

Comment: Nice answer actually I have suggestion  change comment *`Never cast malloc's return value`* to *`Never cast malloc's return value in C`*

Comment: No need to snprintf, sprintf would suffice since you made sure the buffer is large enough. BTW, it's p, not puser. And there are too many closing braces in the snprintf line.

Comment: Checking p for NULL, than i might set value of errno? Like:

    `if(p==NULL) {
    errno = EINVAL;
    return NULL;
    }`

is it good?

Comment: @WernerHenze `snprintf()` not needed here (because allocated correct) but it is preferable and safe.

Comment: @user2590319 its updated to handle `malloc` error. Regarding `errno`, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699596/how-to-set-errno-value