# How to re-develop the sys-function "system()" cleanly?

Tags: c, process, exit-code

I have to develop my own C function `system`. To do that, I use the call-system `fork` to create a child process and it has to execute the command given to `system`, calling `exec`.

What I've wrote seems to work fine (it compiles and executes without any error).

The problem concerns my function `system`'s return (called `mySystem` in my code). For example, in my child process, if I give an nonexistent shell to `exec` (the latter returns -1), my child process stops with an exit code of -1 because I told it to do that. But : my parent process, which retrieves this exit code thanks to a `wait(&status)`, returns... 255 and not -1 !

I don't understand why. I paid attention to use the macro WEXISTATUS in my `mySystem`'s return.

Could you help me to know why my parent process doesn't return -1 (the exit code of its child process) please ? Thank you in advance.

My src (there are a lot of comments) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pid_t pid;

int mySystem(char*);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int result = mySystem("ls");
    fprintf(stdout, "%i", result);

    return 0;
}

int mySystem(char* command) {
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1) {
        perror("Fork");
        return -1; // An error occurred => return -1
    } else if (pid == 0) { // The child process will do the following
        execl("BLABLABLABLA MAUVAIS SHELL BLABLABLAA", "sh", "-c", command, NULL); // If this call doesn't fail, the following lines are not read
        perror("Exec"); // If (and only if) execl couldn't be called (bad shell's path, etc.)...
        exit(-1); // ..., we stop the child process and this one has an exit code equaled to -1
    }

    /*
     * NOW, the child process ended because... :
     * 1. Either because of our "exit(-1)" after the "perror"               (our source-code)
     * 2. OR because of an "exit(-1") of the command passed into the execl  (source-code of the execl's command)
     * 3. OR because of the "exit(0)" of the command passed into the execl  (source-code of the execl's command)
     */

    // The parent process will execute the following lines (child process ended)
    int status = -1;
    if(wait(&status) == -1) { // We store into the var 'status' the exit code of the child process : -1 or 0
        perror("Wait"); // Note that because we have only one process child, we don't need to do : while(wait(&status) > 0) {;;}
        return -1;
    }

    return WEXITSTATUS(status); // Our function mySystem returns this exit code
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does WEXITSTATUS(status) return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465039/what-does-wexitstatusstatus-return)

Comment: What does the documentations say? What did you not understand in the documentation?

Comment: Ah I read again the documentation, and I think my mistake is bound to "This consists of the least significant 8 bits"... Mmmh I can't return a positive value. I will cast the return to `signed char`.

Comment: BTW, [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_08_02) the exit code for "program not found" in the shell as 127.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following picture:
[image]

Where each of the 2 blocks is 8 bits (so total 16 bits).
Now you pass `exit(-1)` which in binary using 8 bits is: 11111111 (the two-complement) that's why you get 255 using `WEXITSTATUS(status)`.

Another example to be clear: let's suppose to call `exit(-6)`, -6 in binary two-complement is 11111010 that correspond to 250, if you make your program run you will see 250 printed on stdout.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is the "status" a "return in main" and an "exit" value ? I think so ; thus, what is the error code ? Is it "errno" ? I thought it could be a "return in main" or "exit" value too.

Comment: No the exit() call doesn't set the errno value I suggest you to look bere for the errno http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699596/how-to-set-errno-value

Comment: Thank you, I already knew this. I just don't understand clearly the vocabulary used for processes (status and error code in the image). I thought "status" was the process' one (so not the return-in-main/exit's value) and the error code, errno. But it's not.